# mysql complains at syntax from go driver

Tags: mysql, go

I'm using the github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql and mysql 5.7.10. I have a function:

```
bulkSetStatus := func(docVers []*_documentVersion) error {
    if len(docVers) > 0 {
        query := strings.Repeat("CALL documentVersionSetStatus(?, ?); ", len(docVers))
        args := make([]interface{}, 0, len(docVers)*2)
        for _, docVer := range docVers {
            args = append(args, docVer.Id, docVer.Status)
        }
        _, err := db.Exec(query, args...)
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

which works if `len(docVers) == 1` but when there are more, resulting in multiple `CALL`s to the stored procedure, it errors:

> Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CALL documentVersionSetStatus(?, ?)' at line 1

I have also tried a newline character between each call but I get the same error. If I run this in mysql workbench with multiple `CALL`s to this procedure it works fine, I'm not sure what is wrong with the syntax here.

I have logged out the exact full text with the arguments and it is as expected:

```
CALL documentVersionSetStatus("9c71cac14a134e7abbc4725997d90d2b", "inprogress"); CALL documentVersionSetStatus("beb65318da96406fa92990426a279efa", "inprogress");
```

Comment: Can you update with the value of `query`? You make it sound like you can copy and paste it's value into mysql workbench and have it work. I'm sure based on the way args work that is in fact not that case and based on the error I would guess the query you're running in mysql workbench simply is not what results from this logic.

Answer (score 3):

`go-sql-driver`, by default, does not allow you to have multiple statements in one query (as you are doing by chaining together multiple `CALL` statements like that) due to the security implications if an attacker manages to perform SQL injection (for example, by injecting `0 OR 0; DROP TABLE foo`).

To allow this, you must explicitly enable it by passing `multiStatements` parameter when connecting to the database, e.g.

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@/dbname?multiStatements=True")
```

Source: https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#multistatements

Comment: thanks for the suggestion I tried updating my connection string to `"usr:pwd@tcp(localhost:3306)/my_db?parseTime=true&loc=UTC&multiStatements=true"` but with no change in the result, still the same error.

Comment: Thanks for this. No warning errors about this, I am starting to hate Go

Comment: this has nothing to do with sql injection btw

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the proc call by doing some manual string interpolation for the parameters instead of using the correct `?` way of doing it:

```
bulkSetStatus := func(docVers []*_documentVersion) error {
    if len(docVers) > 0 {
        query := strings.Repeat("CALL documentVersionSetStatus(%q, %q); ", len(docVers))
        args := make([]interface{}, 0, len(docVers)*2)
        for _, docVer := range docVers {
            args = append(args, docVer.Id, docVer.Status)
        }
        _, err := db.Exec(fmt.Sprintf(query, args...))
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

so I swap out the `?` for `%q` and us `fmt.Sprintf` to inject the parameters, I should note that slugonamission's answer is partially correct, I did need to add the connection string parameter `multiStatements=true` in order to get this to work with my other changes. I will log an issue on the github repo it looks like there may be some param interpolation issue when there is more than one statement, I think the error was happening because the mysql db was trying to run the script with `?` literals in it.